# VIM with Xdebug: Does the Help Window ever change?

Tags: vim, php, xdebug

When using VIM with Xdebug, the following Help window appears:

```
[ Function Keys ]                 |                   
  <F1>   resize                   | [ Normal Mode ]   
  <F2>   step into                |   ,e  eval        
  <F3>   step over                |                   
  <F4>   step out                 |                   
  <F5>   run                      | [ Command Mode ]  
  <F6>   quit debugging           | :Bp toggle breakpo
                                  | :Up stack up      
  <F11>  get all context          | :Dn stack down    
  <F12>  get property at cursor   |
```

Does this window ever change? If it doesn't, how can I prevent it from coming up when I open the Xdebug debugger? I have the functions memorized already!

This is on VIM 7.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the newer [Vdebug](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug) instead.

It works just like the vim script by Seung Woo Shin, so you won't have to change your workflow. The help window is gone in favour of :help Vdebug.

Comment: Thanks, Stan. Vdebug looks to have some other nice features as well.